# Get error messages Chrome packaged app

Tags: google-chrome-app

How can I see error messages when running a Chrome packaged app? I've been running the app in the browser and using DevTools but this technique has it's limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to inspect app windows, you can reach them at `chrome://inspect/#apps`

Or, as [Daniel mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26884774/934239), use the [Developer Tool app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc).

Answer (score 0):

### General Chrome Debugging

By opening

```
chrome://inspect/#apps
```

you may debug all Apps and Extensions.

You may also like the official [Google Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc)

### Debugging Chrome Extensions

As described in the [chrome developer Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) you can activate the developer mode within the settings. Afterwards an `inspect popup` option is avaialbe when you right-click an app-icon.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I just found an official Developer Tool from Google and added it to the answer. If this answer helped you to solve your problem, please consider accepting it as the correct answer by checking the checkmark.

Comment: I would remove the non-Developer Tool part altogether. It does not apply to Chrome Apps anyhow.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for your hint, I updated the answer and added more useful information. Oh, I hadn't realized you also added this information meanwhile.